# Scala implicit with variable argument list

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, variadic-functions

I have library method taking variable argument list and producing data

```
class Data
def process(elems: String*): Data = new Data
```

and I want my strings to be implicitly converted to `Data`

```
implicit def strToData(ts: String): Data = process(t)
```

so I can write something like

```
val data: Data = "one"
```

but I want tuples of strings to be implicitly converted too. I've added another implicit

```
implicit def strsToData(ts: String*): Data = process(ts: _*)
```

it compiles fine, but conversion fails

```
val data: Data = ("one", "two")
val dat3: Data = ("one", "two", "three")
val dat4: Data = ("one", "two", "three", "four")
```

with

```
found   : Seq[java.lang.String]
required: this.Data
val data: Data = Seq("one", "two")
```

Is there any way to convert tuples implicitly, or a reason why it can be achieved?

**Update:** Tuples can be of any arity.

Comment: Are you sure Tuples can be of any arity? I think max is 22 (see http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Tuple23.html vs http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Tuple22.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While all the warnings in @NikitaVolkov's answer apply in double force, you *can* write a version that accepts any arity of tuple, as well as any case class:

```
implicit def prod2data(Product p): process((p.productIterator.toSeq):_*)
```

Answer (score 5):

1. `ts: String*` is not a tuple, but an `Iterable`. You can't convert iterable to tuple, because tuple is a static type and its arity is resolved at compile time. Emil H answered how you can do an implicit conversion from tuple.
2. Transparent implicit conversions from one type to another type is a common pitfall and are greatly discouraged. Instead you should apply a "wrapper" approach, or use "Value Classes" since Scala 2.10:

   In Scala 2.9:

   ```
   implicit def stringStringTupleExtender (ts : (String, String)) =
     new {
       def data = process(ts)
     }
   ```

   In Scala 2.10:

   ```
   implicit class StringStringTupleExtender (val ts : (String, String)) extends AnyVal {
     def data = process(ts)
   }
   ```

   Then you'll use it like so:

   ```
   val data : Data = ("sdf", "lsdfj").data
   val data1 : Data = "sdf".data // if you do the same for String
   ```
3. If you're looking for dynamically resolving any input collection, then, guess what, you should use a collection, not a tuple.

   In Scala 2.9

   ```
   implicit def seqExtender (ts : Seq[String]) =
     new {
       def data = process(ts)
     }
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   val data : Data = Seq("sdf", "lsdkfjsdl", "ldsfjk").data
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create a implicit conversion from a tuple to `Data`:

```
implicit def strTplToData(ts:(String, String)) = process(ts._1, ts._2)
```

Then you could do:

```
val data: Data = ("one", "two")
```

Comment: Is there another solution than to write function for every tuple arity?

Comment: I do not think there is an elegant way of achieving that simply.